# Combine two images in android java

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing

So i have two images stored locally on an SD card in android and i want to combine them into one image. Its hard to explain so i going to link to a picture for a better example of how i want to take the first two images and combine them into the last.

[image: http://img850.imageshack.us/i/combinedh.jpg/]

Comment: http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2012/08/mearge-images.html..refer this one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create your target `Bitmap`, create a `Canvas` for it, use `Canvas.drawBitmap` to blit each source bitmap into your target bitmap.

Answer (score 12):

I am generally using following function [from Jon Simon](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas) to combine two Bitmap passed as argument and get combined Bitmap as output,

```
    public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) 
{ 
    Bitmap cs = null; 

    int width, height = 0; 

    if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
      width = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); 
      height = c.getHeight(); 
    } else { 
      width = s.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); 
      height = c.getHeight(); 
    } 

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 

    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null); 
    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth(), 0f, null); 

    return cs; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to go about this would probably be to use two ImageViews in a RelativeLayout. You can position the ImageViews on top of each other in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Hitesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077388/1617737), but with parameters to specify the position of the foreground image:

```
public static Bitmap mergeBitmaps(Bitmap bitmapBg, Bitmap bitmapFg, float fgLeftPos, float fgTopPos) {

    // Calculate the size of the merged Bitmap
    int mergedImageWidth = Math.max(bitmapBg.getWidth(), bitmapFg.getWidth());
    int mergedImageHeight = Math.max(bitmapBg.getHeight(), bitmapFg.getHeight());

    // Create the return Bitmap (and Canvas to draw on)
    Bitmap mergedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mergedImageWidth, mergedImageHeight, bitmapBg.getConfig());
    Canvas mergedBitmapCanvas = new Canvas(mergedBitmap);

    // Draw the background image
    mergedBitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBg, 0f, 0f, null);

    //Draw the foreground image
    mergedBitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmapFg, fgLeftPos, fgTopPos, null);

    return mergedBitmap;

}
```